# connection between two pc without switch

Tags: router, network-core

I am new to networking. I have a small confusion. Can two pc be connected directly using straight through cable without any router or switch?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But with a crossover cable. That's easy to figure out yourself. You may have questions about the firewalls and configs.

[wikipedia wants to help you :-)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, "It depends." If the ethernet ports on one or both of the PCs support Auto MDI/MDIX, then the answer is, "Yes," otherwise, the answer is, "No."

Most modern PCs have ethernet ports which support  Auto MDI/MDIX, so the answer is probably, "Yes," but you need to double check your equipment.

Comment: Gig: yes (because it's auto MDX) 10 or 100: needs a crossover. (I've never seen a 10/100 *NIC* that was auto. Switch ports, sure, but not a nic.)